# Infinite orthormal set in an inner product space is closed, bounded and non-compact in the metric space with the induced metric by the inner product

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Assume an inner product space $V$ has an infinite orthonormal set $S$. 
Let $d$ be the metric induced by the inner product.

Show that $S$ is closed, bounded and not compact in the metric space $(V,d)$.

I honestly have no idea how to approach this question -- any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|x-y\|=\sqrt2$ if $\{x,y\}$ is orthonormal. All the facts follow from this: a sequence in an orthonormal set can converge only if it is eventually constant, so the orthonormal set contains all its limit point. Since the norm of each element is $1$ the set is bounded. It is not compact because a sequence of distinct vectors in the  orthonormal set has no (Cauchy, hence no )convergent subsequence.